# Should i buy expression engine? or is dead project?

Tags: ee2

Hello guys first of all sorry for my bad english , never i use expression engine, i was reading in his web and looks amazing, but in a lot of blogs and forums, i saw about is a little abandoned , and the support suck , what u think guys? i am a little company trying to find solutions , with a strong plataform and good support , if ee is dead , you have other alternative? processwire? yesterday i founded statamic looks cool is no database and they claim can handle complex and big sites (and is cheap) .

Thanks guys for you time and answers.

Comment: ExpressionEngine certainly isn't dead, and we have a great support community here. Unfortunately, opinion based questions don't fit the Q&A format here very well. If you want to have more of a discussion the #eecms hashtag on Twitter is a great resource.

Answer (score 5):

No ExpressionEngine isn't dead or abandoned, although it seems to have had a rocky road in the past year or so with some long term bugs not getting resolved, but it's still a strong commercial option. There's quite a few users who have voiced opinions (quite rightly), because of the direction and progress that EE has taken, that doesn't make it a bad CMS and it continues to be a leading commercial offering.

I've tried a lot of CMS's and although I favour Wordpress for "budget" sites, no other CMS allows for the freedom and unlimited scope as ExpressionEngine does. And that's why I continue to use it.

ExpressionEngine has a good grounding and large add-on library (http://devot-ee.com), although each project tends to have a license overhead now that I normally allow for around $500+ or more depending on the complexity. That's not to say you need that budget, but if you want all the bells and whistles and top quality build, or complexities such as multi-language, commerce, etc, you have to pay for it.

Both Statamic (http://statamic.com) and Craft (http://buildwithcraft.com) have been created from developers who have very strong background in EE and although I've not had a chance to use either, I expect them to be extremely good offerings, albeit still young projects.