# What the Stigma of EE these days?

Tags: ee

I remember when I was still actively using it Ellislab was making decision after decision that just pissed people off including me. Has anything changed for the better since then or do they still follow the same path?

I ask because I still have one big site running on EE that I'll be investing more time into shortly. And I'm not sure yet if I want to port it to another CMS or keep running it on EE.

Comment: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11593/should-i-buy-expression-engine-or-is-dead-project/11600#11600 - same old story, same reply. Well worth a read: http://masuga.com/blog/2014/01/deciding-on-a-platform-winner-craft-cms Importantly though - read the comments and replies from Ryan.